# netCDF data cut at prime meridian

Tags: latitude-longitude, netcdf

I am quite new to GIS.

I have two sources for my netCDF data. The spatial reference for both is GCS_WGS_1984. One of the rasters has a gap along the prime meridian as it appears in the picture below.

[image: gap on meridian 0:]

I suspect this is because the longitudinal range is 0-360 so I asked the person who generates the data to change it to -180 to +180. The result shown in the image below is not desirable as I would like to have a focus on Europe.

[image: change in longitudinal range]

I was wondering if there are any settings/environments I can adjust at import or afterwards that would get rid of that middle line.

Comment: What software are you importing it into?  And can you show the structure of the netcdf file with something like `ncdump -h file.nc`

Comment: I'm importing it into ArcMap and the data type is nc_long.